# How to use an array of strings to handle the cases in a switch statement in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array

```
    public static string[] commands =
    {   
        "command1",
        "command2",
        "command3",
        "command4",
        "command5",
        "command6",
        "command7"
    };
```

I want to use the array in the function

```
    public static bool startCommand (string commandName) {
        //stuff
        if (commandName == commands[0]) {
            //stuff
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //stuff
            switch (commandName) {
                case commands [1]:
                    //stuff
                    break;
                case commands [2]:
                    //stuff
                    break;
                case commands [3]:
                    //stuff
                    break;
                case commands [4]:
                    //stuff
                    break;
                case commands [5]:
                    //stuff
                    break;
                case commands [6]:
                    //stuff
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            //do stuff
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The error that this is giving me is "A constant value is expected" for each of the cases.

I could use if and else statements, but I think the switch statement looks better for this.

Unless I've missed my mark, my array is of constant strings, so this should work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Sorry if this is a newb question, I've been programming with C# for about four days.

Comment: Try a Dictionary<string, Action>

Comment: I just looked up actions, neat.  Do you mean I should try them instead of the switch statement?

Comment: Indeed! Then you can pass your `commandName` in as the key to the dictionary and invoke the associated action.

Comment: The array contains constants, but is not a constant itself.  Basically you could change the value of `commands[1]` to something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type. A `Dictionary` is basically a collection of Key-Value pairs, something we can take advantage of for what you're attempting to achieve.

Using the example you've given, the implementation would look like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> commandsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
commandsDictionary.Add("Command1", () => Console.WriteLine("Command 1 invoked"));
commandsDictionary.Add("Command2", () => Console.WriteLine("Command 2 invoked"));

commandsDictionary["Command2"].Invoke();
// Command 2 invoked
```

As you'll have noticed, I've introduced the an Action delegate without any parameters.

---

To introduce a parameter, just specify it as a type argument, like this: `Action<int>`

```
Dictionary<string, Action<int>> commandsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>>();
commandsDictionary.Add("Command1", (i) => Console.WriteLine("Command {0} invoked", i));

commandsDictionary["Command1"].Invoke(1);
// Command 1 invoked
```

---

If you want to return a value from the delegate you're invoking, use the `Func` delegate, an easy to remember rule with `Func` is that the **last** type parameter is always the type being returned, so `Func<int, string>` would be equivalent to a method with the following signature `public string Foo(int i)`

```
Dictionary<string, Func<int, string>> commandsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, string>>();
commandsDictionary.Add("Command1", (i) => { return string.Format("Let's get funky {0}", i); });

string result = commandsDictionary["Command1"].Invoke(56963);
Console.WriteLine (result);
// Let's get funky 56963
```

---

---

---

## Reference

I've added this section to aid those who do not yet know what a delegate is... it's all actually rather simple.

---

#### Delegates

A `Delegate` is a `Type` that represents **references** to **methods**. They're just like variables that you declare to reference objects, except instead of objects, they reference methods.

A delegate can be instantiated with a **named method** or an **anonymous function** such as a lambda expression (which is the type I've demonstrated above).

---

#### The Action Delegate

The `Action` `Delegate` has a return type of ***void*** and defines its signature with type parameters.

```
void Example()
{
    // Named method
    this.NamedActionDelegate = NamedMethod;
    this.NamedActionDelegate.Invoke("Hi", 5);
    // Output > Named said: Hi 5

    // Anonymous Function > Lambda
    this.AnonymousActionDelegate.Invoke("Foooo", 106);
    // Output > Anonymous said: Foooo 106
}

public Action<string, int> NamedActionDelegate { get; set; }
public Action<string, int> AnonymousActionDelegate = (text, digit) => Console.WriteLine ("Anonymous said: {0} {1}", text, digit);

public void NamedMethod(string text, int digit)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Named said: {0} {1}", text, digit);
}
```

---

#### The Func Delegate

The `Func` `Delegate` is similar to the Action Delegate the difference being that Func never returns ***void*** and thus will always ***require*** at least ***1 type argument*** and as mentioned earlier, the type argument specified last dictates the return type of the delegate.

```
void Example()
{
    // Named method
    this.NamedFuncDelegate = NamedMethod;
    string namedResult = this.NamedFuncDelegate.Invoke(5);
    Console.WriteLine (namedResult);
    // Output > Named said: 5

    // Anonymous Function > Lambda
    string anonyResult = this.AnonymousFuncDelegate.Invoke(106);
    Console.WriteLine (anonyResult);
    // Output > Anonymous said: 106
}

public Func<int, string> NamedFuncDelegate { get; set; }
public Func<int, string> AnonymousFuncDelegate = (digit) => { return string.Format("Anonymous said: {0}", digit); };

public string NamedMethod(int digit)
{
    return string.Format ("Named said: {0}", digit);
}
```

Comment: are variables local to the action?  For example, if I define parentObject ob;  then I call an action that sets ob = new childObject();  will that work?

Comment: You can write actions that take parameters, as well, but scoped variables will also be captured in the action closure.

Comment: @Damien using the example I've given above, the `Action<int>` delegate has access to the locally scoped `i` variable of type `int`, it also has access to variables within the scope of the `Example()` method

Comment: @Damien I realise that you're quite new to C#, so I've added a quick rundown as to what delegates are and how to utilise them. If any of us have managed to answer your question, please do mark the answer that was most helpful to you as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks.  A dictionary of anonymous delegates worked perfectly.  I originally had a map of strings to functions and a function for each of my cases, but that was cumbersome.  With what you suggested I changed the switch statement to CC = commandActions[commandName](); much nicer, and a lot less code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the switch with the array commands, instead use of compare with the items of commands use the index statement like this:

```
public static string[] commands =
{   
    "command1",
    "command2",
    "command3",
    "command4",
    "command5",
    "command6",
    "command7"
};

public static bool startCommand(string commandName)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(commands, commandName);

    //stuff
    if (index == 0)  // commands[0]
    {
        //stuff
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //stuff
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:  // commands[0]
                //stuff
                break;
            case 2:  // commands[2]
                //stuff
                break;
            case 3:  // commands[3]
                //stuff
                break;
            case 4:  // commands[4]
                //stuff
                break;
            case 5:  // commands[5]
                //stuff
                break;
            case 6:  // commands[6]
                //stuff
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        //do stuff
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. However `case 1:` corresponds to `commands[1]` which is `"command2"`. So fix that throughout. There should be no `if`, start with `case 0:`. The `default:` section is good and will catch the `-1` (not found in array) case.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize as an answer, change it to something like this:

```
        Dictionary<string, Action> commands = new Dictionary<string,Action>();
        commands.Add("command1", () => {});
        commands.Add("command2", () => { });
        commands.Add("command3", () => { });

        Action action = null;
        commands.TryGetValue(commandName, out action);
        if (action != null) 
            action();
```

You can make your dictionary static, or possibly readonly if you want:

```
    static void Command1() { }
    static void Command2() { }

    static readonly Dictionary<string, Action> commands = new Dictionary<string, Action>(){
        { "command1", Command1 },
        { "command2", Command2 }
    };
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize a variable passed as out parameter. Since `out` ensures that called method has to set the reference during its execution, C# compiler won't cry if you just declare the variable and you don't set it

Comment: While true, a) it doesn't harm anything and b) it is good form in many programming languages.  Of course, we could just wait until C# v6 to inline the declaration and definition as the result of an `out` parameter.  http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/15/c-6-0-features-part-3-declaration-expressions.aspx

Comment: It doesn't harm anything, ok, but in my case I don't care how other languages may behave. We're talking about C# and in C# an reference passed as out parameter doesn't need to be initialized outside the method being called...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are ok with constant strings, what about defining a static class:

```
public static class COMMANDS 
{
    public const string COMMAND1 = "command1";
    public const string COMMAND2 = "command2";
    public const string COMMAND3 = "command3";
    public const string COMMAND4 = "command4";
    public const string COMMAND5 = "command5";
    public const string COMMAND6 = "command6";
    public const string COMMAND7 = "command7";
}
```

and then use it with the switch statement:

```
//stuff
if (commandName == COMMANDS.COMMAND1)
{
    //stuff
    return true;
}
else
{
    //stuff
    switch (commandName)
    {
        case COMMANDS.COMMAND2:
            //stuff
            break;
        case COMMANDS.COMMAND3:
            //stuff
            break;
        case COMMANDS.COMMAND4:
            //stuff
            break;
        case COMMANDS.COMMAND5:
            //stuff
            break;
        case COMMANDS.COMMAND6:
            //stuff
            break;
        case COMMANDS.COMMAND7:
            //stuff
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    //do stuff
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CommandExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var cmdName = "Command1";

            // Create an instance of the command class using reflection
            Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("CommandExample." + cmdName);
            if (type == null) { /* Cannot find command. Handle error */ }
            var cmd = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ICommand;

            cmd.Exec();
        }
    }

    interface ICommand
    {
        void Exec();
    }

    class Command1 : ICommand
    {
        public void Exec()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing Command1");
        }
    }
}
```